# Matrix multiplication in inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R^n}$ be such that 
\begin{equation}
x>y.
\end{equation}
Is it possible to premultiply or postmultiply the above inequality by a positive definite diagonal matrix, say $A$, of order $n$, i.e., does the following inequality hold?
\begin{equation}
Ax>Ay.
\end{equation}
If it is true, how?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. I assume that $x > y$ is meant componentwise, i.e. $x_i > y_i$ for all $i$. Then $(Ax)_i = a_{ii}x_i$ where $a_{ii}$ is the $i$th diagonal entry of $A$. By assumption that is a positive number, hence $(Ax)_i > (Ay)_i$ for all $i$. So the answer is YES.

Answer (score 3):

If "$x>y$" means that $x_i>y_i$ for every $i$, then yes, of course this is preserved by multiplying by a positive definite *diagonal* matrix.

A diagonal matrix is positive definite exactly when the diagonal elements are all positive. So multiplying by $A$ simply makes each $x_i>y_i$ into $a_{ii}x_i > a_{ii}y_i$ which has the same truth value when $a_{ii}$ is positive.